# Sorting result is not correct of radgridview in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-grid, radgridview

When I use the default build in sort function in the radgridview whitout any code, the sort result is wrong. Does anyone know why this happened?
[image]

Comment: It may be related with your *locale*.   . `.` can be a *decimal separator* or *group separator* depending on the *CultureInfo* .

Comment: it looks like that max column sorted the values by different variable name. like 180.0<187.9 and 47.45 <47.88 while I did set any multiple columns to sort.

Comment: `180015.... < 187932.... < 474518.... < 478801....` read my first comment again.

Comment: Oh, I finally get it, thank you very much!